# Import two modules in Main file, and call methods in them from each other

Tags: python

I'm new to Python, but so far I know that in some languages you can "Inderectly" import a module and see it's content for a module that will be imported after that one.

For example, these modules:

> main.py
>
> ex1.py
>
> ex2.p

And in them I have

**Ex1.py**

```
def Test1():
    print('this is a test')
```

**Ex2.py**

```
def Test2():
    Test1()
    print('this is another test')
```

**Main.py**

```
from Ex1 import Test1
from Ex2 import Test2

Test2()
```

In python, this will throw me a error saying that `Test1()`is not defined in Ex2. But since I imported `Test1` before `Test2` and then called a method from Test2 in Main.py (where both functions are imported), shouldn't this be allowed? I don't know if there's a way to do this, but some languages, like AutoIt, allow you to do so. I found nothing on this during research.-

Comment: you should import Ex1 in Ex2.py

Comment: Sure, that works. But is there a way around? Suposing Ex1 is a log modulethat I'll use in several other modules, I don't want to import them in all of them. Its easier to import once in the main file. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because of how Python resolves names.

In `Ex2`, at runtime, `Test2` will look for `Test1` *in its own scope*; in other words, for a function with the name `Ex2.Test1`. This can be achieved by a `from Ex1 import Test1` statement.

Conversely, in `main`, when you execute `from Ex1 import Test1`, the name of the function is now `main.Test1`, which does not match the name of the function that `Test2` is looking for.

It is *possible* to do that with some `sys.modules` magic, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

First off, it should be `ex1` and in your python file, so that the names of the modules are correct.

Secondly, import `ex2` in `ex1`. This should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Sure, that works. But is there a way around? Suposing Ex1 is a log modulethat I'll use in several other modules, I don't want to import them in all of them. Its easier to import once in the main file. Is that possible?

Comment: You can give definitive path to python. `import sys` and then `sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/the/directory')` and then `import module_name`. You would have to do it for every file. This is a hack obviously, and highly not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't work like that, it isolates module namespaces to prevent awful bugs.